# Regex to match 2-20 alphanumeric characters, allowing a single hyphen anywhere in the string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to learn how to use preg_match. I want users to be only allowed to sign up with username between 2-20 characters which can contain a-zA-Z0-9.

Now the tricky part where Im getting lost, I want them to be able to include one hyphen anywhere in the username so,

```
-Brad = TRUE

--Brad = FALSE

B-Rad = TRUE
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can build this up step-by-step. You want a username that consist of 2-20 specific characters:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}$
```

Now you want to allow a single `-` character somewhere in there (the trick part):

The `-` character is only allowed if it is not followed up by another `-` to the end of the string:

```
[-](?=[^-]*$)
```

This is a so called *Lookahead assertion*. Combined with an alternation, the regex completes to:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[-](?=[^-]*$)){2,20}$
```

Compared to the other answers given, this one respects your length specification.

Comment: WOW! - Thank you for this answer. You also explained it well, I was just about to give up trying and settle for using two preg_match statments.

Comment: @BradleyRoberts: You're welcome. You wrote you want to learn *and* the pattern in your question was not that obvious so there was something to tinker with ;) Good luck with your regex progress, it takes some time to think in that language but it's really powerful. You can also try to improve by trying to answer regex questions that pop-up here, because of the other answers there is often something to learn.

Answer (score 3):

You could use preg_match with:

```
\w*-?\w*
```

It will ensure that one hyphen exists, but will also match just a hyphen. You can also use:

```
(\w*-?\w+)|(\w+-?\w*)
```

To avoid matching only a hyphen. Or you can check if the match has length > 1.

You said to be able to, so I assumed the hyphen isn't a requirement. If it is, remove the ? in the regex.

If you plan on matching in a sentence, you could use a word break (\b) with the \w+ part. If you're using this on a trimmed string then add ^ and $ to the start and end respectively to avoid matching `--Bra-d` as true.

Comment: I want the users to be allowed one hyphen only. They do not have to have a hyphen. I want to limit them to 2-20 length of username only other characters which will be included can be a-zA-Z0-9.

Comment: do these patterns reject multiple hyphens?

Comment: There allowing everything. I want to limit them too alphanumeric with 1 hyphen anywhere in the username.

Answer (score 3):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\-?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

is the regex

Edited: Quick solution for length: use a second preg_match with `^.{2,20}$`

Comment: Yeah this is working but how can I limit it to 2-20 characters all together?

Comment: Thank you for your edit, I will have a play around and make a php function save me keep typing it out in places :)

Comment: @Bradley Roberts Anytime. I think it would be better though to use `strlen` for length validation

Comment: Check the length as well within the regex, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9657218/367456).

Comment: Using a regular expression to check string length?  Really??

Comment: @Phoenix I said it would be better to use `strlen`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd do it:

```php
if (preg_match(
    '/# Match pwd of alpha-numbers allowing one optional dash.
    ^                 # Anchor to start of string.
    (?=.{2,20}\z)     # Assert length is from 2 to 20 chars.
    [a-zA-Z0-9]*      # Zero or more alpha-num before dash.
    (-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?  # Optional dash and more alpha-num.
    \z                # Anchor to end of string.
    /x', $text)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```